# Image need to be replaced with another image each time with a different button click in html page

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 buttons in a html page and each button is associated with an image.
I need the working as follows,

ButtonA, ButtonB, ButtonC and ImageA, ImageB, Image C.

When ButtonA is clicked, ImageA should be displayed. 
When ButtonB is clicked, ImageA should be **REPLACED** with ImageB.
When ButtonC is clicked, ImageB should be **REPLACED** with ImageC.
Again when ButtonA is clicked ImageC should be **REPLACED** with ImageA.

I can use only javascript and html for coding. Is it possible to accomplish it? If yes, Can you give me sample code which i can refer?

Comment: Yes you can accomplish.

Comment: Can you give me an example which i can refer?

Comment: Yes it's possible. And to you second question : https://i.imgur.com/Fpl50GR.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do it like this

**SIMPLE HTML AND JS (Beginner approach for learning)**

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='https://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulbon.gif'">Turn on the light</button>

<img id="myImage" src="https://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulboff.gif" style="width:100px">

<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='https://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulboff.gif'">Turn off the light</button>
```

**Using jQuery (Practical Approach)**

```js
$('.light_switch').click(function(){

    var action= jQuery(this).attr('data-toggle');
   if(action=="on"){
        jQuery('#myImage').attr('src', 'https://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulbon.gif');
      }
  else{    
    jQuery('#myImage').attr('src', 'https://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulboff.gif');
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="light_switch" data-toggle="on">Turn on the light</button>

    <img id="myImage" src="https://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulboff.gif" style="width:100px">

    <button class="light_switch" data-toggle="off">Turn off the light</button>
```

Comment: You litterly copied that code from w3schools.com. Why not refering to site as source of you're awnser?

Comment: Source of awnser: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_lightbulb

Answer (score 0):

Please include any Javascript Code that you have attempted. If you simply want to set the source of an image through javascript, this can be seen in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/JoelAndHowe/joLtoq25/) fiddle.
Using a custom attribute on a button, as so:

```
<input type="button" class="imgBtn" value="A" id="btnA" imageSrc="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" onClick="changeImage(this)">
```

Then, through hooking this button up to a function, passing in the button, you can access this attribute and set the image accordingly. Such as:

```
    function changeImage(buttonClicked) {
  var imageDiv = document.getElementById("newImg");
  imageDiv.src = buttonClicked.getAttribute("imageSrc");
  }
```

However, using JQuery, this could be made simpler, without requiring an onClick function:

```
$('.imgBtn').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#newImg').attr('src', $(this).attr('imageSrc'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example approach to do this using Javascript and HTML
for example: if you have 3 images inside images folder

```
+Images
 -a.png
 -b.png
 -c.png
```

then you can do in javascript:

```
    var a = "images/a.png";
    var b = "images/a.png";
    var c = "images/a.png";

   //this function will be used to change image source whenever button is clicked.
    function changeImage(i)
    {
        var img = document.getElementById("img");
        switch(i)
        {
            case 'a': img.setAttribute('src',a); break;
            case 'b': img.setAttribute('src',b); break;
            case 'c': img.setAttribute('src',c); break;
            default: return false;
        }
    }
```

Your HTML may look like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Button A" onClick="changeImage('a');">
<input type="button" value="Button B" onClick="changeImage('b');">
<input type="button" value="Button C" onClick="changeImage('c');">
<img id="img" width="320px" height="220px">
```

Comment: Why use `img.attr('src')` instead of `img.src`? Is there some advantage by using `attr` instead of `src`?

Comment: @RichardMauritz I don't know If any there is some misconception but not exactly if there is any difference. and thanks to focus on it I forgot to use javascript syntax instead of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, written in pure `JavaScript`. As you said, use as reference ;)

Just read the comment lines i provided to each `var`, `function` and `event`

```js
(function() {
  
  /**
   * In this example i store the image urls inside a javascript object
   */
  var images = {
    a: {'url': 'http://www.markramseymedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/oneperson.jpg'},
    b: {'url': 'http://kazguu.kz/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/vecher-poe%60zii.jpg'},
    c: {'url': 'http://poskok.info/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/pozija.jpg'},
  }
  
  /**
   * Get all the buttons
   */
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
  /**
   * Get the image element
   */
  var img = document.getElementById("changeMe");
  
  /**
   * This function will be called if a button gets clicked
   */
  changeImage = function() {
    
    /**
     * Get the `data-show` value to determine which image has to be shown
     */
     var image = this.dataset.show;
     /**
      * Change the `style="display: none;"` to `style="display: block;"`
      */
     img.style.display = "block";
     /**
      * Set the `src` attribute, so the image will be loaded dynamicly
      */
     img.src = images[image].url;
  }
  
  /**
   * Register a click event on each button
   */
  for(var i = 0;i < buttons.length;i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", changeImage);
  }
  
})()
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 150px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<img id="changeMe" style="display: none;" />

<button id="buttonA" data-show="a" class="button">Image A</button>
<button id="buttonB" data-show="b" class="button">Image B</button>
<button id="buttonC" data-show="c" class="button">Image C</button>
```